# Itō's formula in stochastic calculus

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

Let $$dI_t=K_t^1dt+H_t^1dB_t\text{ and }dJ_t=K_t^2dt+H_t^2dB_t.$$
With Itō's formula how to show that
$$I_tJ_t=I_0J_0+\int_0^tI_sdJ_s+\int_0^t J_sdI_s+\int_0^tH_s^1H_s^2ds?$$

My idea: let $f(x,y)=xy$. How to use Itō's formula here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be derived from 2-dimensional Ito's Lemma with $f(x,y)=xy$.

Applying Ito's Lemma we obtain 
$$(\star) \ \ \ \  d(I_tJ_t) =I_tdJ_t + I_tdJ_t + \frac{1}{2}dI_tdJ_t +  \frac{1}{2}dJ_tdI_t=I_tdJ_t + I_tdJ_t + dI_tdJ_t$$

Knowing Ito's table, that is, $dtdt = dtdB_t = dB_t dt = 0$ and $dB_tdB_t = dt$

we obtain that $$dI_tdJ_t =H_t^1H_t^2 dB_tdB_t =H_t^1H_t^2 dt  $$

thus by integrating both sides of $(\star)$ we obtain

$$I_tJ_t - I_0J_0 = \int_0^t I_sdJ_s + \int_0^t J_sdI_s + \int_0^tH_s^1H_s^2 ds$$

and so

$$I_tJ_t = I_0J_0 + \int_0^t I_sdJ_s + \int_0^t J_sdI_s + \int_0^tH_s^1H_s^2 ds.$$

After rearranging the above we also obtain *integration by parts formula*

$$\int_0^t I_sdJ_s  = I_tJ_t - I_0J_0 - \int_0^t J_sdI_s - \int_0^tH_s^1H_s^2 ds.$$